# Flex 4.5, setting locale for datefield does not work

Tags: apache-flex, locale, datefield

For some reason, setting the application locale to nl_NL does not affect my datefield components.

Dates are still displayed in english language/formatting.

I tried using the following:

But this does not work. Am I doing something wrong?

I guess I could make a custom datefield component, where I supply the dutch translations for those dates, including the formatting, but this is a way I rather not like to go...

Answer (score 0):

you can use formatString to specify the dateFomat you wish to use.

```
<mx:DateField id="dateFieldEnd" formatString="YYYY/MM/DD" .. />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
<mx DateField id        = "dateField" 
              dayNames  ="["S", "M", "D", "M", "T", "F", "S"]"
              monthNames="["januari", "February", "March", "April", "May",
                           "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", 
                           "November", "December"]" />
```

Along with the formatString option you should get what you are looking for.  I know those are all English except January, but I don't know the Dutch month names...