# Flex 4.6 Arabic (Hijri) Calendar datepicker component

Tags: apache-flex, calendar, locale, arabic, hijri

I am working on a Flex project that requires an Arabic (Hijri) calendar/datepicker, although I have failed to find any such components to date and been unable to satisfactorily customise the existing Flex components.

I have read up on how to convert a date from Gregorian to Hijri via the DateTimeFormatter using the locale property to specify the language/calendar type  (http://blogs.adobe.com/globalization/en/formatting-with-alternate-calendars-in-flex/), but this does not seem to work on the DateField component which I was originally using for my input and datepicker.

I've also read about other issues using the locale property on the DateField component which suggested just modifying the day and month names ([Flex 4.5, setting locale for datefield does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823473/flex-4-5-setting-locale-for-datefield-does-not-work)), but that is not sufficient for the Hijri calendar which has a different way of counting days, months and years to the Gregorian calendar. Not to mention needing to order the dates right-to-left.

As this SWF is going to be embedded in a PDF I can't work around it by employing an external calendar and reading the data back into the app.

Does anyone know how I can achieve a Hijri calendar in Flash/Flex?